# jQuery capture current frame from jwplayer live stream

Tags: jquery, html, nginx, jwplayer, live-streaming

I'm currently trying to use jQuery to grab the current frame being displayed by JWPlayer. I have searched the [JWPlayer API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference) and there doesn't seem to be any function that obviously fetches the frame.

I'm using avconv (ffmpeg) and nginx to stream a camera feed through HLS and then reading that stream in the browser. Because this is a live stream I don't have access to the Buffer API funcitons.

I'm looking to have a solution that will allow the user to click somewhere on the video, grab that frame, analyse the image and display data about where the user clicked. This needs to work whether the user has flash or not.

I know how to grab a frame from an html5 video tag by drawing to a canvas and using canvas.toDataURL(). And I believe that it is possible to have JWPlayer display it's video through a video tag but everything I've tried as resulted in JWPlayer converting the designated element into some kind of flash object.

My end goal is to pass a base64 encoded image along with the coordinates of the click to the server to do the analysis.

**UPDATE**

Since I am streaming a live feed from a camera I cannot send an mp4 through a pipe because mp4 requires seekable data. Which means that I have to send flv through the pipe, however, flv format cannot be read in browsers without some kind of flash player.

As such the solution will either have to involve intercepting the stream server side, converting to an mp4, and then passing it in real time to the client side (which seems either extremely difficult or extremely hacky) or it will have to involve manipulating a flash object.

Comment: The closest thing we have is something like this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29406/a-poster-less-preview

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I can tell the poster-less preview isn't actually getting the frame. It's simply playing the video for a brief second then pausing it.

Comment: Yes. We don't really have a way to actually capture the frame.

Comment: Would you happen to know of a generic javascript flash api that might be able to help me out here? Either that or a different flash player?

Comment: I do not know of one, sorry...

Comment: If I'm able to generata thumbnail on the capture-side (Say from the mobile phone) I should be able to generate the frame that way though.